# Looping with Object Operators

Tags: php, mysql, loops, calendar, operators

I am playing around with [PHP Calendar](http://coreyworrell.com/calendar/) (Corey Worrell) and had a question regarding instance looping. In order to initialize the calendar, I have to output this:

```
$calendar->standard('today')
        ->standard('prev-next')
        ->standard('holidays')
        ->attach($event1)
        ->attach($event2)
        ->attach($event3)
        ->attach($event4)
        ->attach($event5)
        ->attach($event6)
        ->attach($event7)
        ->attach($event8)
        ->attach($event9)
        ->attach($event10)
        ->attach($event11)
        ->attach($event12)
        ->attach($event13)
        ->attach($event14)
        ->attach($event15)
        ->attach($event16)
        ->attach($event17);
```

Each **->attach($event#)** outputs an event on the calendar. I want to loop through these numerically incrementing event names but adding a for loop anywhere in that code breaks everything, outputting this error:

> PHP Catchable fatal error:  Argument 1 passed to
>   Event_Subject::attach() must be an instance of Event_Observer, null
>   given, called in /calendar/index.php on line 75 and defined in
>   /calendar/classes/event_subject.php on line 21

Here is the loop I've tried:

```
$calendar->standard('today')
        ->standard('prev-next')
        ->standard('holidays')
        for ($inc = 0; $inc <= $number_of_events; $inc++) {
            if ($inc == $number_of_events) {
                ->attach($$event_name);
            }
            else {
                ->attach($$event_name)
            }
        }
```

How can I loop inside of here? My events are stored in MySQL and I am doing an **$number_of_events = $result->num_rows** to determine the number of events returned. The **->attach($event#)** would loop, repeating until the total **$number_of_events** is hit.

Comment: What does the loop you tried using look like?

Comment: Updated question to show the loop code.

Comment: Why are you using variables named `$event1`, `$event2` etc instead of putting them in an [array](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)?

Comment: I am pulling them from the database, @Don'tPanic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's called method chaining. Each method of the class returns an instance of the called object via `$this`, allowing you to stack method calls. Method chaining is possible because the function returns a reference to your object.

Because each function in the class that supports method chaining returns the calling object, you can just re-assign the returned object back into the original `$calander` variable;

```
 for ($inc = 0; $inc <= $number_of_events; $inc++) {
        if ($inc == $number_of_events) {
            $calander = $calander->attach($event1);
        }
        else {
            $calander = $calander->attach($event1);
        }
    }
```

Additionally, if you wanted to iterate through variable names, you could use a variable variable inside your loop;

```
$variable = "event".$inc;

$calander = $calander->attach($$variable);
```

So this would become `$event0,` `$event1`, `$event2`, etc.

Comment: I like your explanation of method chaining, and it makes sense to use variable variables given the circumstances, but the if and else branches in your code seem to be doing exactly the same thing, and it probably isn't necessary to reassign `$calendar` to itself when attaching events without using method chaining.

Comment: Your post, prior to edits, caused me to retry the solution. I'll award the accepted answer to you for this. Thank you!

Comment: @sheldon glad I could be of some help

Comment: @Don't Panic: You're absolutely right. I just copied the OP's code, and inserted my own. 

I haven't actually used the library myself. If it's possible to attach events and the object retains its state, then you're right, you could just call the method without having to re-assign the object to itself.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with the loop is that there is nothing in front of the `->` operator. The `->` references a property of an object, but you do not provide it with an object. You could solve it by putting `$calendar` in front of the lonesome operators (`$calendar->...`), but it would still not be very pretty code.

I suggest this instead:

I think you could just add the events one by one inside the loop I assume you are already using to create the `$event1`, `$event2`, etc. I don't know what you are using to get the data out of the database or what your table structure looks like, but I will provide an example for MySQLi. It should be easy to modify for other alternatives.

```
//Add the standards.
$calendar->standard('today')
    ->standard('prev-next')
    ->standard('holidays');

//Connect to the database here and query for the events using MySQLi.

//Loop through the results.
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    //Create an event from the database row...
    $event = calendar->event()
         ->condition('timestamp', $row['TIMESTAMP'])
         ->title('Hello All', $row['TITLE'])
         ->output('My Custom Event', $row['OUTPUT']);
    //...and attach it.
    $calendar->attach($event);
}
```

This is not code to be copy-pasted directly, but more of a suggestion about how to organize it.

Also, for the future, you should not name variables `$name1`, `$name2`, etc and then use `$$` to reference them. Use [arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) instead.

Comment: I tried this out (with modifications, of course), but it spits out a PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_OBJECT_OPERATOR in /calendar/index.php on line 58

Comment: Redeclaring **$calendar** is causing an error, I think.

Comment: I am not redeclaring `$calendar`, I am simply referencing the object multiple times instead of chaining the method calls. That should be fine - I have checked the source of the plugin. While you can use method-chaining (multiple `->` in a row), you do not have to. What line is 58?

Comment: Sorry, you're right: referencing, not redeclaring! It was a late night! lol

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution. Not sure why changing this to reference **$calendar** each line worked, but it did. Thanks everyone.

```
$calendar->standard('today');
$calendar->standard('prev-next');
$calendar->standard('holidays');

for ($x = 1; $x <= $number_of_events; $x++) {
    $event_name = "event".$x;
    $calendar->attach($$event_name);
}
```

Comment: Still, I really do recommend you to use an array to store the events in. And thanks for sharing your solution.

Comment: It works because $calendar->attach($event_name)->attach($event_name) is a method chain. The first call to attach() *returns* a reference to $calandar, allowing you to call ->attach($event_name) on that reference. When working with function return values, just imagine the return value where the method/function is. You're performing an operation on the *return* value. That's why your original code didn't work. Calling ->attach($event_name) on its own is seen as a single statement. There's no object attached to the calling method.